# How to know if you are writing 'good' javascript- lots of ways to do same thing?

Tags: javascript

I have only really looked at python before where there is one way to do anything, javascript is really hard to get an order of how to do things for me.

For example, in the elequentjavascript teaching series, one of the module tests was to output the average ages of each century from an 'ancestry' object. My answer was vastly different from the websites, is it just experience which shows you the correct way?

Website solution:

```
function average(array) {
  function plus(a, b) { return a + b; }
  return array.reduce(plus) / array.length;
}

function groupBy(array, groupOf) {
  var groups = {};
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    var groupName = groupOf(element);
    if (groupName in groups)
      groups[groupName].push(element);
    else
      groups[groupName] = [element];
  });
  return groups;
}

var byCentury = groupBy(ancestry, function(person) {
  return Math.ceil(person.died / 100);
});

for (var century in byCentury) {
  var ages = byCentury[century].map(function(person) {
    return person.died - person.born;
  });
  console.log(century + ": " + average(ages));
}
```

My attempt:

```
function displayCenturyAges(array, centuryStart, centuryEnd) {
    var ages = 0;
    var tempObject = {};
    for (var i = centuryStart; i <= centuryEnd; i += 100) {
        tempObject[i] = array.filter(function (people) {    
            return (people.died - i) < 100 && (people.died - i) > 0;
        }).map(function (people) {   
            return people.died - people.born;
        });  
    }
    for (var key in tempObject) {    
        ages = 0;
        if (tempObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            tempObject[key].forEach(function (elements) { 
                ages += elements;
            });
            console.log(key + " average age: " + ages / tempObject[key].length);
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have only really looked at python before where there is one way to do anything" --- you're soooooooo wrong.

Comment: Your attempt isn't bad, so don't be discouraged. I do believe it's a style that comes with experience as you learn the patterns that do and don't work for different situations. Just try to focus on good-practices and code cleanliness and you'll do fine. Look at open source projects, the good ones  do a great job of showing how you can improve stylistically and otherwise. And don't think that javascript is the only language where there are multiple ways to the same goal. Any scripting language (and many others) is going to give you that power.

Comment: This question is *very* opinion oriented, and will likely be voted for closure as off topic.  However, I think the priority when working with a project depends on your audience.  Unless you are writing an Open Source Library for public consumption, you should "Make It Work" first, Refactor for your team practices second, Worry about what others think of your code *never*.

Comment: Read http://javascript.crockford.com/ and/or buy Crockford's "Good Parts".

Answer (score 1):

I would say "good" Javascript is a combination of clarity and optimization, which is dependent on the type of project you are working on. If you are writing code for an enterprise company, then the code should have optimization as its primary concern, which may sacrifice clarity, but good documentation should take care of that. If you are working with a group of friends on a fun project, then I would say not to worry too much about optimization, but make sure your code is clearly understandable so that other people know what is going on. I hope this helps!

Comment: "If you are writing code for an enterprise company, then the code should have optimization as its primary concern" --- enterprise does not need that. Enterprises respect fitting into deadlines so the tops could get a bonus. Irregardless what rubbish was shipped to production.

Comment: Wrong conception, many enterprices that work on software projects have code standards and follow models to get a clean and clear code, with the correct optimization target.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of Software, never exist a "correct way to do" something, exist many ways to solve a problem, it depends of each person, and every one that works, can be applied to a correct answer.

When we talk about which one works better, we entered on another face to the software.
I called: "quality of software development proccess" and "Software engineer", those subjects talk about a better way to developt a software.
It depends on your target it have many ways to make your code and software better, some examples:

Clearity:

- Software standards (you can make your own standard)
- Design patterns (Singletone, Factory, EAV, Observe, etc...)
- Models (MVC model, HMVC, view oriented).

Optimization:

- Algoritms and data structures
- RUn time Optimization
- User interface designs
- DB Query optimization

Quality:

- Implements process models
- Test cases

So exist one correct way?, no, exist many ways to solve it, Which is better? deppends on your approach, which is correct? every one that works and fit to your espectations.